# As400 db connectivity issue(NegativeArraySizeException)

Tags: ibm-midrange

this is my code

```
final AS400 as400 = new AS400(host); 
as400.setServicePortsToDefault(); 
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver()); 

final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:as400://" + 
         host + ((port != null && !port.equals("")) ? (":" + port) : ""), 
         username, password); 
return connection;
```

========================================================================

[This exception occurs while connecting to as400 db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZFbo.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the connection string you are building there from host and port, etc is what you want it to be.  Maybe build in a separate line and verify it is coming out correctly.

Comment: What port are you connecting do?  If you are not connecting to database host server port, then you will see errors because the data coming back from the server does not match the database host server protocol.  The default database host server port is 8471.  The only reason you would need to change the port number is if you need to use a firewall proxy between the client and the server.